# Filtro de busqueda dinamico con consultas preparadas

Tags: php

Quiero hace un filtro de búsqueda dinámico, es decir, filtrar datos en la base de datos según lo que el usuario quiera buscar. Actualmente, lo que hago es:

```
// creo la base de la consulta
$query = 'SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE 1 '; 

// voy añadiendo las condiciones a medida que el usuario lo indica
if(isset($_POST['filtro_1'])){
    $query .= 'AND Condicion_1 = "' . $_POST['filtro_1'] . '"';
}
if(isset($_POST['filtro_2'])){
    $query .= 'AND Condicion_2 = "' . $_POST['filtro_2'] . '"';
}

$result = $conexion -> prepare($query);
$result -> execute(array());
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que las consultas sean preparadas, pero no se como estructurar el código para que añada una condición u otra dependiendo de lo que el usuario quiera buscar.

Actualmente, el código que tengo es este y al ejecutarlo me da este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php:63 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php(63): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php on line 63

```
<?php   


require("datos_conexion.php");
$user = '';
$name = 'marcos';
$user = 'gmarsi';

$data = 'SELECT User_User FROM users WHERE User_Punc > 0 ';
if ($user != '') {
    $data .= " AND User_User = :user ";
}
if ($name != '') {
    $data .= " AND User_Name = :name ";
}
$resultado = $base -> prepare($data);

if ($user != '') {
    $resultado -> bindValue(':user', $user);
}

if ($name != '') {
    $resultado -> bindValue(':name', $name);
}
$resultado -> execute(array());

while($row = $resultado -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<br>'.$row['User_User'];
}

?>
```

El archivo de conexión:

```
<?php



$base = new PDO("mysql:host = localhost; dbname=databaseName", 'userName', 'password');

$base ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$base -> exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

?>
```

Comment: ¿cual es el error que te da?

Comment: ¿Que es lo que quieres hacer? Poder usar `PDO`, ¿pero no sabes como se usa? ¿Sabes como se usa pero te da error?

Comment: Te sobra una comilla al final de $_POST['filtro_1']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en esta línea:

```
$resultado -> execute(array());
```

Ya has hecho *bind*  de los parámetros y valores que querías, no hace falta pasarle un array a `execute`, y en especial un array vacío (motivo por el que recibes el error, porque el número de parámetros en el array es 0).

El problema se soluciona fácilmente quitándolo:

```
$resultado -> execute();
```

Otra cosa sería que en lugar de hacer `bindValue` lo que hicieras es poner los valores en un array, y entonces pasar ese array a `execute`... pero entonces de nuevo corres el riesgo de que no se haya especificado ni `$user` ni `$name`, en cuyo caso recibirías el error de nuevo.